# Call Mirasvit Sphinx Search from own controller?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, controllers, search, sphinx

I am using Mirasvit Sphinx Search with good success. However, I would like to handle certain types of requests using my own controller, from which I would perform a search and process the search results. (I want to call, not override, the Mirasvit Sphinx Search controller.) I am able to trigger my own controller. How do I call the Mirasvit Sphinx Search code and process the search results?

Answer (score 0):

From your controller action:

```
// Mirasvit Sphinx Search gets search string from request object so
// explicitly set search string on request object.
Mage::app()->getRequest()->setParam('q', 'query-string');

// Get Mirasvit Sphinx Search results.
$collection = Mage::helper('searchindex/index')->getIndex('mage_catalog_product')->getCollection();
```

Then work with $collection as you would any other product collection in Magento.